# how to calculate height of parallelogram

Tags: geometry

Sorry, it's been long time doing this basic maths ! but I am wondering if I can calculate height to calculate area of parallelogram if two side of quadrilateral is given

Example
length = 6
breadth = 4

how to calculate area of parallelogram (1/2*B*h)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to compute the area by only knowing the measures of lenght and breadth. In the case of a rectangle, you can because you know that one of the angles meassures $90^{\circ}$.

A formula which can be applied is
$$
A = \tfrac{1}{2}\times\text{Length}\times \text{Breadth} \times \sin(\theta),
$$
where $\theta$ is the measure of one (any) of the angles of the parallelogram.

Comment: so $\text{Height}=\text{Breadth} \times \sin(\theta)$

Comment: Maybe lose the $1/2$ factor in the formula for the area. It is a formula for a parallelogram, not a triangle.